# Postgresql combine date and time column

Tags: postgresql, time

I'm trying to combine date column and time column into one.

The data format I have is:

```
id      date              time
---------------------------------------
1    2020-01-01    1900-01-01 12:46:00
1    2020-01-01    1900-01-01 16:30:27
1    2020-01-02    1900-01-01 15:23:00
```

I've found the following code most frequently as solutions online, and tried few times/ways around it but I keep getting error of `unable to identify an operator '+' for types 'DATE' and 'DATE`, which makes me think that this is probably wrong approach?

```
 cast(date as date) + ' ' + cast(time as datetime) as datetime
```

I'd appreciate if anyone can help!

Comment: The problem is you are trying to combine a date and a datetime. So something like: `select '2020-01-01'::date + '1900-01-01 12:46:00'::time; 2020-01-01 12:46:00`

Comment: You're trying to add a space ' ' to a date and that won't work, a character isn't a date.

Comment: ahhhh I just realized this too! I had tried ::time (instead of datetime) before too but had the ```+ ' ' +``` that was giving me error.. I tried ```date::date + time::time``` and it now works! Thanks so much @AdrianKlaver and @Frank Heikens

Comment: Why are you storing a "time" in a `timestamp` column? It seems that column should be defined as `time` - or maybe even combine both columns into a single `timestamp`